# Open photo using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT with write permissions

Tags: android

I have a problem using Storage Access Framework in Android 5+, I am unable to get write permissions on photos opened using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT.

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i, 10);

//created objects like this in onActivityResult
Uri uri=data.getData();
DocumentFile df=DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);
ParcelFileDescriptor pfdr=null, pfdw=null;
//below code in try catch block
pfdr=getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r"); //null means no read
pfdw=getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w"); //null means no write
```

Just to verify if any other method works, I created a small app in which I picked an image using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT, used Cursor to get its file name and created following objects:

1. File object using file name - gives neither read nor write access (checked using canRead() , canWrite() functions)
2. DocumentFile object using Uri - gives only read permission for both ACTION_OPEN.. and ACTION_CREATE.. (checked using canRead() , canWrite() functions)
3. Tried to get two file descriptors one with read and other with write permission but only got read file descriptor object, other generated exception (Media is read-only).

Below is screenshot of app I created just to verify.
[image: screenshot of test app]

**What am I doing wrong, I there any other way to get write permission to opened photos in Android 5+.**

One more thing I would like to mention, for some files I do get write access but I don't understand when and how it works.

I have included MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission in manifest too.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the code that you are using and which storage provider you are choosing in the Storage Access Framework's UI. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor) showing read/write access to text files via the Storage Access Framework. I have no problems with this sample app, testing on Nexus devices and using "Internal Storage" in the Storage Access Framework UI.

Comment: Added some code for reference

Comment: I guess accessing photos is different than accessing text files. I have checked above on pics in Internal and external(sdcard) memory both

Comment: @prodev: This is bad habit of deleting question after getting answer. why are you wasting our time?

Comment: @un-lucky: There must be some mistake, I haven't deleted any answered questions. Please tell me which question you are talking about